# Web Scraping with Node JS, Puppeteer and Cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, cheerio

I was trying to do some Web scraping. My goal is to find get find all `<H></H>` tags and text that are directly following them. Example Would be:

```
<div>
 <h2>heading 1</h2>
 <p>text 1</p>
 <h3>heading 2></h3>
 <p>text 2</p>
</div>
```

Result for this would be:

```
[
 {
        "title": "heading 1",
        "tag": "h2",
        "text": "text 1"
    },
    {
        "title": "heading 2",
        "tag": "h3",
        "text": "text 2"
    },
]
```

My Solution for this :

```
let headings = $('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6');
let result = {}
    for (let i = 0; i < headings.length; i++) {
        let newObj = {};
        //preparing title from heading
        newObj.title = this.#cleanText($(headings[i]).text());

        //tag name of the heading
         newObj.tag = $(headings[i])[0].name;
        if($(headings[i]).nextUntil($(headings[i + 1])).find('img')){
          numberOfImage++; 
        }
       $(headings[i]).nextUntil($(headings[i + 1])).find('img').remove()
       $(headings[i]).next().find($(headings[i + 1])) && "got new heading"
        //getting html markup as string between current heading and next one
       if (i === headings.length - 1){
           newObj.text = $(headings[i]).nextAll().toString();
       }else{
           newObj.text = $(headings[i]).nextUntil($(headings[i + 1])).toString();
       }
       result.content.push(newObj)
   }
```

As you can see I'm getting it alright if all `<h></h>` tags are siblings but I'm not being able to handle any nested headings like:

```
<div>
 <div><h3>heading 1></h3>
 <p>text 1</p>
  <h2>heading 2</h2>
 </div>
 <p>text 2</p>
 <h3>heading 3></h3>
 <p>text 3</p>
<div>
 <h3>heading 2></h3>
 <p>text 2</p>
</div>
</div>
```

I need Result to be like this:

```
[
 {
        "title": "heading 1",
        "tag": "h2",
        "text": "text 1"
    },
    {
        "title": "heading 2",
        "tag": "h3",
        "text": "text 2"
    },

    {
        "title": "heading 3",
        "tag": "h3",
        "text": "text 3"
    },
]
```

It would be really helpful if anyone can give me a solution for this

Comment: Your markup and expanation has no `<img>` yet your code takes pains to deal with these tags. Are you sure the example markup isn't oversimplified? What does it really look like?

Comment: I won't take any image or figures, will take only that contains tags like p,li,span etc

Comment: Just walk the DOM using `$('*').each(element=> addCodeHere)`. Check if the element tagName is in array '['H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H4', 'H5' 'H6'].  If you encounter a header element, check the previousElementSibling and/or the nextElementSibling to determine if it is a p tag.

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like:

```
$('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').get().map(h => {
  return {
    title: $(h).text(),
    text: $(h).find('~ p').first().text()
  }
})
```

I'm using ~ which is following sibling selector (newer versions of cheerio only)

Comment: Thank you but this still does not give any text under first h tag, I have edited the question. So you can now see what I was expecting

Comment: Yes, If there's no following p sibling then it will be empty.